# Using the Photoshop API, can I change the tracking value of a specific text character in my textItem?

Tags: javascript, python, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is it possible to change specific text properties in PS text using a script? I've gotten the ability to insert text going with:

```
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument
layer_scenario_text = doc.ArtLayers["TextLayer"]
text_of_layer = layer_scenario_text.TextItem
text_of_layer.contents = "Text to change"
```

But is it possible to change say, the tracking value for selected characters with scripting? Looking at the API docs, I've found the `textItem.tracking` property, but would I be able to have it apply to just ONE part of the string? E.g. the word `change` in my example would have a tracking of -20 but everything else in the string stays the same?

Many thanks!

Comment: I seem to remember there was a similar question a while ago and the conclusion was that it is not possible to target single string parts in Photoshop. This would be easily possible in InDesign though, so depending on the task at hand you might be able to do this in InDesign.

Comment: This is unfortunate to hear! Would the same be doable in Illustrator perhaps? This is the second most common format for the project I'm attempting and I've not tried InDesign yet!

Comment: Not sure about Illustrator, sorry. Do you need open files in the end? Because if not, and you need a .jpg or .png instead, InDesign might still be a solution.